# how to select mesh island by its area?

Tags: geometry-nodes, faces

I'd like to create **multiple** floors based on the area of **geometry island**.

right now it's based on face area, and if the faces are not similar it's not working fine.

any suggestion ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

(blender 3.6.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Accumulate Field* node, and group by *Island Index*:

[image]

Comment: thank u, it works perfectly